# ¿Como configurar codeigniter para los estilos e imagenes?

Tags: codeigniter-3

buen dia, quisiera saber si alguien me puede decir como se configura el codeigniter para que este se pueda ver en una red interna y tambien saber si es con la misma configuracion o es con otra para poner la pagina en un hosting.

para lo de los estilos css, me encontre una linea para poner en el .htaccess, pero no me funciono, esta linea;

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|css|robots.\txt)
```

Comment: La carpeta (assets) normalmente va en la raiz del proyecto, al mismo nivel que la carpeta (application), no necesitas una configuración .htaccess

Comment: lo tengo en la raíz del proyecto, pero cuando quiero abrir la pagina en otra computadora de la misma red, no me muestra ni los estilos css ni las imagenes

Comment: cómo las estás llamando? lo usual es `href="<?php echo base_url("css/normalize.css");?>">` (o le pones un helper que le agregue la versión para los caches)

Comment: no lo llamo asi como tu dices

Comment: pues es la forma para que reconozca el url base del CI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ambos casos con la misma configuración debería funcionar, lo que sí, deberías cambiar el `.htaccess` por el siguiente, ya que no te va a funcionar así como lo tenés:

#### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|php|script|styles|js|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Y luego configurar un **VirtualHost** para poder usarlo localmente o dentro de una misma red.

Desde windows, con xampp, podés acceder a `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` (o dónde esté instalado el xampp) y escribir lo siguiente:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName ejemplo.com
    ServerAlias www.ejemplo.com
    DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\CarpetaCodeigniter
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Luego en el archivo `hosts` de windows en `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` agregar al final:

```
127.0.0.1   www.ejemplo.com
```

Y con eso vas a poder acceder desde cualquier navegador a ese URL y sirve para cuando necesites implementar eso a un servidor, salvo que esos pasos ya no serían necesarios.

---

**Nota**: ese htaccess lo que hace es que oculta el `index.php` de la url y la hace más amigable.